# how to show a tooltip with rich:message

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tooltip

sorry for my poor English.
I am using RichFaces 4.2.2.Final.
I want to display only icon when validation is error.
And I want to display the error message as tooltip on mouse over.
Is this possible?
according to [document](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html_single/#sect-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages-richmessage), It seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with Richfaces 4.X but when I wanted to implement a tooltip, I tried it the following way...

```
 <h:outputText title="#{log.message}" value="#{fn:substring(log.message,0,10)}..."  rendered="#{(fn:length(log.message)>=10)}"/>
 <h:outputText title="#{log.message}" value="#{log.message}" rendered="#{!(fn:length(log.message)>10)}" />
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you your reply.
I decided to use notifyMessages instead of tooltip.

```
# xthml
<rich:notifyMessages ajaxRendered="true" stayTime="2000" nonblocking="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" />
<rich:message ajaxRendered="true" for="clientId" showDetail="false" showSummary="true" escape="false" /> 

# backing bean
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "&nbsp;", message);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("clientId", msg);
```